# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a web widget on jquery from the tutorial found [here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/).

Basically, it checks if jQuery is loaded otherwise loads it. My widget merely shows a button and onClick shows a fancybox which loads an iframe.

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
            scriptLoadHandler();
          }
        };
    } else { // Other browsers
        script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||      document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        // We can use jQuery 1.4.2 here

        /**** LOAD FANCYBOX ******/
        $.getScript("fancyboxURL");

        // I also tried loading fancybox here but that didnt work either
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
}

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

When loading the page I am getting the below errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7:19
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

**Some attempts**

In the file which the error `Property "$" ....` error is coming from, it currently reads

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

From other threads I have found that I should try with

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

but that only gave me `Property "jQuery" of object is not a function`.

I know the code works fine because if I manually include `jQuery` in my html file it works.

My HTML file below:-

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- IF I UNCOMMENT THE BELOW LINE IT WORKS! Add jQuery library -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- load widget -->
<script src="http://mywidgetURL.../widget/myWidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="widget-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the markup generated when I Inspect Element on Chrome seems to indicate that jQuery is loaded.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: But the jQuery library should be included by the widget javascript. Okay let me edit my question to show the javascript.

Comment: when you are including jQuery... there is a possibility that when the `$(document).ready(..)` code is executed... jQuery may not have loaded....

Comment: where are you using $(document).ready(function(){.. code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three problems (probably more).

You use `jQuery.noConflict(true)`, the `true` tells *jQuery*, that you want to not only restore the `window.$` that was set before *jQuery* was loaded but also the `window.jQuery`.

If no *jQuery*  was loaded on the page the global object `window.jQuery` stays `undefined`.
To get fancybox working it needs jQuery to be available in the globale scope, which is not that case in your situation. Thats why you get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:2

Then you have this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js

This shows that you load `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` somewhere, at a time where `jQuery` is not available in the global scope (most likely same reason as above), trying to access `fancybox` which is not assigned to jQuery because of the above reason.

About the last error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

If this happens in your posted code when you call `$(document).ready( ... )`, then it is because jQuery is not assigned to `$` (`noConflict`). But `jQuery(document).ready( ... )` in the `main` should work (you should fix the errors in the order they occur, to be sure that the others are not follow up errors)

Another problem you have, that will appear when you you solved the other problems is with:

```
 $.getScript("fancyboxURL");

 // I also tried loading fancybox here but that didnt work either
 $(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

`$.getScript("fancyboxURL");` loads scripts async, so in nearly every case *facnybox*  is not loaded at the time you call `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`.

**EDIT**

For widget code I would suggest that you host all your libraries yourself or use libraries that support AMD and a loader where you can create a loading context for the modules. 
I currently can suggest you one, because we have an own loader.

Another solution would be to host all your jQuery plugins yourself and wrap them into a `callback` function.

Something like that:

```
 function myWidgetScript_s7d8f6_fancybox(jQuery, $) {
       //the original code that is in the fancybox.js file
 }
```

> myWidgetScript_[some number to avoid conflicts]_[name of you modified script]

And in your code do something like this

```
 jQuery.getScript( "modified.fancybox.js", function() {
       myWidgetScript_s7d8f6_fancybox(jQuery, jQuery);
       jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();

 });
```

Comment: wow thank you so much for shedding so much light. I am going to try and solve these one by one now. Any hints that you have will be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: So am I right to say that the first thing I should look at is to have jQuery in the global scope?

Comment: Well that won't help you much with the chosen library, but for widgets I highly recommend to use AMD capable libraries and load these e.g. with  [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

Comment: thank you very much. I am no expert in javascript so the RequireJS site does look quite hard to digest for a start. If you have any tutorials or sorts I will be deeply appreciative. :)

Comment: @user1258600 Updated my answer. I would not recommend to make your `jQuery`, `fancybox` and all other dependencies to be available in the global scope, because this has a high risk of conflicts, either making your widget behave wrong, or _destroying_ the page where it is include. Anyway if you don't have much experience in JS it is probably not the best idea to write a widget. Correctly isolating code can be painful and requires you to be able to read and fully understand error messages and scoping.

Comment: For clarification when writing widgets you really should use `window.jQuery.noConflict(true)` with `true`.  But this makes it hard to include other plugins if you are not an experienced js developer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure any javascript you do on the webpage is inside the "We can use jQuery 1.4.2 here" section. If it's outside of that section, the browser will not be aware of jQuery.

Comment: yup I did all the loading within the "We can use jQuery 1.4.2 here" section like you mentioned but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The fancybox widget uses jQuery. So you have to include it, before you use it.

So the flow would be

- include jQuery (no need to check, if it's the first thing anyway)
- include fancybox
- Use document ready to initialize fancybox, as above.

Something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://mywidgetURL.../widget/myWidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
          $(".fancybox").fancybox();
     });
</script>
```

Comment: yup that's what I did, or at least I think I did it that way. Have edited the "We can use jQuery 1.4.2 here" section of my code above to show more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script>
   // code to load jquery version 1.4.2 if not exists
   (window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2')  || 
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<!-- include your fancybox plugin to work properlly -->
<script src="path_of_your_js_folder/fancybox-plugin.js"></script>
<script>
    // code to initialize your fancybox
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the best solution for a widget code, because it requires that this whole bunch of html code has to be included into the html code, with no chance to be modified later.